# knockout custom select binder with update function

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, custom-binding

I am trying to develop a custom select binder but I am not able to understand how to develop the update functionality. Currently [this](http://jsfiddle.net/harsh611/4zsu9pv2/3/) is what I have done. I want custom binder to handle this type of data

```
[{
    message: "Hello",
    Value: 1
}, {
    message: "Hi",
    Value: 2
}, {
    message: "Bye",
    Value: 3
}, ]
```

Comment: I want to get the selected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as I understand it: You are using the [Bootstrap Fullscreen Select](http://craftpip.github.io/bootstrap-fullscreen-select/), and you can initialize it, but when you select a new value, no observable gets updated. Basically, we need to know when a new value is selected.

Since the way the widget works is to pop up a screen of options and allow you to select one, and then close that popup, *and* the widget provides the ability to do an `onClose` callback, that's all we need.

I'm using the standard convention of a `value` binding in the select. When the widget closes, if the new value is different from the bound value, I will update the bound value to the new value selected in the widget.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.menu = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var valueObservable = allBindingsAccessor().value;
        $(element).mobileSelect({
            onClose: function () {
                var newValue = $(this).val();
                if (newValue !== valueObservable()) {
                    valueObservable(newValue);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

As a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4zsu9pv2/4/

Comment: Thanks..I was struggling to understand the functionality